# Inject to "transactional" journey an opted-out Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We want to set up a logic for a Boolean in Salesforce called "Sync to Marketing Cloud" to be false for those who have hasOptedOutOfEmail set to True.

We also want to set a Transactional email journey to be sent out on new Orders in Shopify, based on the Order being created on Salesforce (Salesforce Entry Source).

Sending a Transactional Email / Journey to an opted-out contact should be possible:
[I wanted to have a detail about auto-suppression (HasOptedOutOfEmail in core/salesforce object value) prevents journey emails from being sent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291717/i-wanted-to-have-a-detail-about-auto-suppression-hasoptedoutofemail-in-core-sal)

Question is:
If the contacts above are set not to sync (are filtered by the boolean), will they enter the journey to receive a transactional email?

Comment: Injection's OK for those with HasOptedOutOfEmail. Just ensure you use a Transactional Send Classification in the setup of any emails in your journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the flag preventing them from being synced only applies to your synchronised data extensions. Injecting contacts into journeys will not be affected.